# Defrag range ioctl not supported in this kernel, please try without any options

Tags: btrfs

I'm trying to compress my BTRFS filesystem for all the files I added before adding `compress=lzo` to `/etc/fstab`. I've booted into a live CD and run the following:

```
sudo mount /dev/mapper/root /mnt
sudo btrfs filesystem defragment -r -v -clzo /mnt
```

I get the following output:

```
ERROR: defrag range ioctl not supported in this kernel, please try without any options.
```

What has gone wrong and is there a way to fix it? My other BTRFS volumes ran this just fine, but they're not mounted as `/`.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. I'm not sure about the cause, but I was able to defragment and compress by specifying one subdirectory at a time, e.g.

```
sudo btrfs filesystem defragment -r -clzo /var
```

Note that I did this on a running file system. Also, it's the -r option that triggers the problem (whether defragmenting / or a subdirectory)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.04, and the solution was that the `PATH` that you give must be the mount-point of your BTRFS volume to defrag.

For instance, I have `sda3` mounted as `@home` on `/home` and the following command fails:

`$ sudo btrfs filesystem defragment -r -clzo $HOME
ERROR: defrag range ioctl not supported in this kernel, please try without any options.`

however, the following works

`sudo btrfs filesystem defragment -r -clzo /home`